# How to delete words containing a specific character in RegEx?

Tags: regex

Using Notepad++'s find and replace feature using regular expressions, I want to get rid of every word with the number symbol (#) attached to it, particularly in the beginning of the word in my case.

For example, how do I make:

> *The #7kfe dog likes #9kea to eat pizza*

into:

> *The dog likes to eat pizza*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Having 4 questions which answer your question, you should mark the best one as accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most editors that have find-and-replace using regular expressions work similarly... in the 'find' field, look for `#\w*` and in the replace field, use  (empty string). This will leave double spaces (the space that was before your word and the space that was after your word)... you can either tweak the expression above to something like `#\w* ?` (so that the space is optional, in case the word in question is the last word of the line), or you can do a second search-and-replace that collapses multiple spaces into one.

Answer (score 3):

Most other responses will give you words starting with `#` which seems to be what you want, but to suit your question in your OP ("*particularly* in the beginning"), this will select every word with a # in it (anywhere):

```
/(\w*#\w+|\w+#\w*)/
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fJ5pL5)

Answer (score 1):

find: `(\W)#\w+`

replace: `\1`

(obviously also set it to regex mode)

The `\W` looks for a non-word character, to ensure the # is at the beginning of a word. The `\1` in the replace puts that character back.

Answer (score 0):

```
#\w*
```

use this regex.

will match every word after `#`

Comment: You rock. I appreciate your help.